# htaccess set main page in sub folder with css/js folder and multi web

Tags: .htaccess

Hello i  have folder project like this

i want main page to call sub folder

example

**localhost/apps** << show page from folder **sites/web1**

**localhost/apps/cso** << show page from folder  **sites/web2**

check this image for structure folder

[image]

im already create .htaccess in **apps/.htaccess**

this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/web1/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sites/web1/index.php [L]
```

i'm already work call **localhost/apps** << show page from folder **sites/web1** but css and js folder not call / not found

so how to

- **localhost/apps/cso** << show page from folder  **sites/web2**
- call folder **sites/web1/css** and **sites/web1/js** 
  when i call **localhost/apps**

help me thank's

Comment: Try using an HTML base tag in header of your webpage ie `<head> <base href="/"></head>` this will tell the server to load your css and js files from the original location instead of looking into the URI. Alternatively to fix this, you could also change your relative css and js links to absolute ones , simply add a leading slash to the path ie `/style.css` .

Comment: @starkeen still Object not found!

Comment: How are you including css and js links to your webpage? can you post an example.?

Comment: @starkeen look > https://jsfiddle.net/q2bmnh0k/